# Using Arduino to create a countdown that unlock a box

Tags: arduino-uno

Am new to Arduino. So permit me if I sound so novice.

I want to create a countdown device (a clock that will countdown or something) that will unlock a box when the time is up.

As an example, let say, I set the clock to start counting down from 2hours, but when it remains 5mins for the countdown to elapse, the box will unlock

What are the things needed for it to work as all examples I see are mostly for opening the door or box when the temperature changes.

Comment: see the BlinkWithoutDelay example.

Comment: Some kind of display to show the remaining time. Either an LCD display, or a 4-digit 7-segment display. For the latter, there there are breakout boards that already have the needed circuitry to driver them. For the latch, you could use a servo. Or alternatively a solenoid.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds as an escape room puzzle.
From an electronic point of view you need something to lock/unlock the box like a servo motor, a stepper motor or (best option) a normally closed solenoid. You might need some components to drive such locking mechanism, like a mosfet or transistor (possibly a darlington), depending on which device you choose and what voltage it requires to operate. Simplest solution is a servo motor which doesn’t require anything, but has a low torque, meaning the box can easily be forced. Most robust and reliable solution is a NC solenoid, common ones are 12V so you’ll need a p-channel enhance mosfet and a couple of resistors to drive it from an Arduino.

To display the time you’ll probably want to go for an LCD, common ones are 16 col x 2 rows, most have an integrated chip to drive them using only a few wires.

Apart from that, you need a battery pack (voltage and power depending on your locking circuit choice) and may be a push button (for safety unlock).

From a software perspective you want to create a loop which starts by locking the box and then counts down the time: when the time left is less than 5 mins it activates the unlocking mechanism circuit.

```
int current = 0;
const int max = 2 * 60 * 60; // 2hrs in sec
const int grant = 5 * 60; // 5mins in sec
bool unlocked = false;

void setup() {
    lock();
}

// executed once every second
void loop() {
    // any safety open check should be performed here...
    // if still locked and less than 5 mins to end
    if (!unlocked && current > max - grant) {
        unlock();
    }
    
    display(current++);
    wait(1000);
}

// does what it is needed to unlock and sets the unlocked variable to true
void unlock() { ... }

// does what it is needed to lock and sets the unlocked variable to false
void lock() { ... }

void display(int secs) {
    int h = secs / (60 * 60);
    int m = (secs / 60) % 60;
    int s = secs % 60;
    // display on LCD the values above with the proper formatting
}
```

A couple of notes:

- if you go for a normally closed solenoid be sure to have a way to get inside the box if something goes wrong with your circuit or if the batteries get drained
- you might want to have a hidden button or other way to force the unlock, especially for debugging and testing

Comment: You should probably have `current = (millis() - startMillis) / 1000;` in `loop()`, and no `current++`.

Comment: I tried to make it simpler to understand, but you are right: I’m not taking into consideration any time spent while looping. Also consider that the loss will almost always be in the order of 10-20ms... but you are definitely right: my “clock” implementation will drift for sure